# OctoberCMS BelongsTo (HasMany) Relation Issues

Tags: widget, relation, octobercms, belongs-to

I have a `Series` model which `$hasMany` `RainLab\Blog\Models\Posts` and when I display this model with `'type' => 'relation'`, in `Posts` form it looks perfectly fine:

[image]

So, I can select one `Series` and assign it to a `Post`. What I wanted to do is to be able to create new series while being on `Posts` page. To do this I tried to use `'type' => 'partial'` for `Series` field. Partial itself contains just:

```
<?= $this->relationRender('series', ['readOnly' => false]) ?>
```

`config_relation.yaml` contents:

```
series:
    label: Series
    view:
        list: $/plugin/models/series/columns.yaml
        form: $/plugin/models/series/fields_simple.yaml
        toolbarButtons: link|unlink|create|add|remove
    manage:
        form: $/plugin/models/series/fields_simple.yaml
```

`columns.yaml` contents:

```
# ===================================
#  List Column Definitions
# ===================================

columns:
    title:
        label: Title
        searchable: true

    post_count:
       label: Posts
       sortable: false

    created_at:
        label: Created At
        type: date
        invisible: true

    updated_at:
        label: Updated At
        type: date
        invisible: true
```

`fields_simple.yaml`:

```
# ===================================
#  Form Field Definitions
# ===================================

fields:
    title:
        label: Title
        span: left
        required: true

    slug:
        label: Slug
        span: right
        placeholder: Slug
        required: true
        preset:
            field: title
            type: slug
```

So, basically, nothing special here. But:

[image]

As you see, it looks terrible by default. And one more issue - when deleting the series (or unlinking, I tried both) it does not refresh the form, values remain there, though the relation is removed in DB.

Am I doing anything wrong here? What is the proper way to nicely display this relation with ability to edit it?

Comment: As per my thinking, After submitting or deleting you can refresh the page.

Comment: @ChiragPatel page partial (part of the form) is reloaded by AJAX and there should come refreshed partial from the server. And it actually comes, but only after the second reload.

Comment: I was facing the same difficulty and then I had created a custom toolbar instead of(toolbarButtons link|unlink|create|add|remove) and placed AJAX method for it and after the operation (save and delete) I had managed it with Redirect:refresh();